# ActionCable channel subscription is not working because channel method isn't executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a small book shop in Rails. Users can write reviews for individual books, which are added to a product's page. I want to use ActionCable to add new reviews to the page, so that it is constantly up to date, and display a small alert notification when a review is added for other users that are currently on the same page.

Therefore I want to set up individual channels for each product based on a product's id. When a user opens a product's page, she should subscribe to the corresponding channel.

To achieve this I am trying to call a method called `listen`, that I added to the ProductChannel class, whenever a new site is loaded by calling `App.product.perform('listen', {product_id: 1})` in JS. But the problem is that although `perform` is called, `listen` is never executed. What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding? Thanks in advance!

Content of `javascript/channels/prouduct.coffee`:

```
App.product = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ProductChannel",
    connected: () ->
        return

    disconnected: ->
        # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
        return

    received: (data) ->
        # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
        console.log("there is data incoming so lets show the alert")
        $(".alert.alert-info").show()
        return

    listen_to_comments: ->
        @perform "listen", product_id: $("[data-product-id]").data("product-id")

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
    App.product.listen_to_comments()
    return
```

Content of `channels/product_channel.rb`:

```
class ProductChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
  end

  def unsubscribed
  end

  def listen(data)
    stop_all_streams
    stream_for data["product_id"]
  end
end
```

Comment: It could be turbolinks, Whats happens when you put App.product.listen_to_comments in the js console ?

Comment: It returns the method as expected. I just discovered that the listen method is irregularly called when submitting a review, which is not the right moment. I can not make sense out of it.

Comment: I suspect that turbolinks:load is firing multiple times. try putting :
i = 0;
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  console.log i++

Answer (score 0):

A connection object has to be instantiated :

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags current_user.name
    end

    def disconnect
      # Any cleanup work needed when the cable connection is cut.
    end

    protected
      def find_verified_user
        if current_user = User.find_by_identity cookies.signed[:identity_id]
          current_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Then you need to broadcast_to the @product

```
class ProductChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end

  def listen(data)
    stream_for @product
    ProductsChannel.broadcast_to(@product)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, Snake. But I did instantiate the connection object and also set up the broadcast. I narrowed the issue down to the `@perform()` method, which returns false on the first call, but true on every further call. I created a new question for it, which is more specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336276/actioncable-channel-subscription-method-perform-returns-false-on-first-call-of

Comment: I'm having same issue with no true from any call to `App.chat.speak("ASA")`

My console logs are showing 
`Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)`

Continuously it means it is not starting correctly can anyone guide?