# ActionCable channel subscription method `perform` returns false on first call of turbolinks:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to call the `listen` method of my ProductCannel class every time the user moves to a new page to adjust the ActionCable channel the user is subscribed to to her location.

I call the method using `App.product.perform('listen', [...])` every time the `turbolinks:load` event fires. The issue is that the `perform` method returns `false` the first time it is called which leads to the `listen` method not being called. But when moving further to another site it changes to returning `true` and calls the method.

Why is it not returning true the first time it is being called? How can I fix that?

Content of `assets/javascript/channels/product.js`

```
App.product = App.cable.subscriptions.create("ProductChannel", {
  connected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received: function(data) {
    console.log("received the data and update stuff now")
    alert("New review has been added")
  },

  listen_to_comments: function(){
    console.log("listening to comments")
    return this.perform("listen", { 
      product_id: $("[data-product-id]").data("product-id")
    });
  }
});

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    console.log("turbolinks ready")
  App.product.listen_to_comments();
});
```

Content of `channels/product_channel.rb`

```
class ProductChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # stream_from "product_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def listen(data)
    stop_all_streams
    stream_for data["product_id"]
  end
end
```

Comment: Any luck on this? I have a simular question.